# Display another widget while value is null

Tags: flutter

I'm making a search feature in my flutter app. I've pretty much gotten everything working, except for one small issue.

Here's the code I got so far:

```
Future<SearchResult> results;
Future<SearchResult> getResults(String query) async {
    var response = await http.get(url + query);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsona = json.decode(response.body);
      return SearchResult.fromJson(jsona);
    } else
      throw Exception("Failed to fetch songs");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
              height: 55,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: searchController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Search for artists"),
                          validator: (input) {
                            if (input.isEmpty) {
                              return "Please enter an artist name";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                          results = getResults(searchController.text);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.search),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              searchResults()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget searchResults(){
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: results.asStream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            print("stuck");
            return Center(child: Text("No data to display.."));
          } else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title:
                    Text(snapshot.data.results[index].trackName),
                    subtitle:
                    Text(snapshot.data.results[index].artistName),
                    leading: Image.network(
                        snapshot.data.results[index].artworkUrl30),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text("Fetching the data..."));
          }
        });
  }
```

So the way this works is that the user enters the name of an artist, once that's done, I run a function where I make an api call to get the songs made by that artist. The results are stored in the results object.

Basically, I want to display a Text widget while the results object is null, and then display the actual results fetched by the api call once the data has been loaded. I've handled the displaying results once the data has been fetched. The issue is, up until the user searches for an artist, results is null.

How can I display some widget while results is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of solving this.

- You can give the future a default value that never completes:

```
Future<SearchResult> results = Future.delayed(Duration(days: 99));
```

In this case, while the user has not made a query, the Widget that will be displayed is the `if(!snapshot.hasData)` part.

- Validade before the return from the `searchResults` method:

```
Widget searchResults(){
if (results==null)
    return Text('No search made yet.');
else
    return StreamBuilder(
         [...]
    );
}
```

(Also, you probably can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) directly instead of a StreamBuilder with a `Future.asStream`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FutureBuilder** instead StreamBuilder

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)