# How to display something while the value is null/loading in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-futurebuilder

I've created a real-time object detection with Tiny YOLOv2 using Flutter app. So far the app managed to detect the object and display its bounding box with the detectedClass and confidence. Then I pulled the detectedClass (the name of the object) and assigned it into my String `_result` variable because I need it to fetch data from Firebase later.

The main issue is when the app is not detecting anything I want to display something like maybe 'Loading...' until the `_result` return the name of the object bcus u see my custom Tiny YOLOv2 takes a lil bit of time before it detect the object. Then, I want to fetch data based on `_result` from the Firebase. So far, I've managed to fetch the data from the Firebase **BUT ONLY** if I hardcoded the name of the object detected. Otherwise the app would return null error if I'm fetching using `_result` variable.

Below is my attempt of displaying the the name of the food and its calorie (which is fetched from the Firebase) based on the `_result` variable but FAILED:

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image:AssetImage('assets/back.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        // child: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, color: Colors.orange, size: 40),
                        child: Text('Press on the camera icon',
                          style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: ()
                        {
                          initCamera();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35), 
                          height: 270,
                          width: 360,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: list,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                          future: dbRef.orderByChild("food_name").equalTo(_result).once(),
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Text("Loading..."),
                                );
                            } else {
                              lists.clear();
                              Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
                              values.forEach((key, values) {
                                lists.add(values);
                              });
                              return ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: lists.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                      int index) {
                                    return
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                              .start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text("Name: " + lists[index]["food_name"]),
                                            Text("Calorie: " + lists[index]["calorie"]),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                  });
                            }
                          })
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error from the above is:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (String, dynamic) => Null))
```

My issue is kinda similar with [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777660/display-another-widget-while-value-is-null) and the solution in there is not working in my case.

I dont know whether its possible to fetch the data from firebase based on the real time input? Otherwise how do I save the name of the object somewhere to make it static(?) I'm really new to Flutter so some guidance on how to code it is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Edited** Btw just want to add it here. This is how I declared my `_result`:

```
_recognitions.forEach((response)
    {
      _result = "${response["detectedClass"]}" + "\n\n";
    });
```

Basically `_result` is just the name of the object detected.

Comment: Do you need to call `snapshot.data.value` and then `values.forEach`? Shouldn't it be `values = snapshot.data.values`?

Comment: I just came across a tutorial in utube on how to display data from firebase and they did it like this so I thought that just the way to do it? I'm still new to Flutter. Is that the reason I cannot fetch firebase data from ```_result```? How do u suggest i do it? Btw thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Add another condition in your future builder `else if (snapshot.hasError)` to see if you are getting a valid response.Declare your values map like this  `Map<String, dynamic> values={ };` then reassign `values`.

Comment: @Saddan thank you for your response. I already did as u told but still got the same error as above where ```(NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.``` I'm convinced that my ```_result``` could display the output because I already tried to just simply display the said variable by putting it inside ```Text``` widget and it works but it just doesn't work when I put it in my query which is ```dbRef.orderByChild("food_name").equalTo(_result).once()```. I think the problem lays on that ```_result``` variable maybe because its a real time input?

Comment: did you check `_result` value after doing this `_recognitions.forEach((response)` iteration?did it in your expected format?I guess when you use `_result` in your query its find nothing and `snapshot.data.value` doesn't return a `map` perhaps its in json format. try with also `json.decode(snapshot.data.value)`

Comment: yes I already did as I mentioned above I display it inside ```Text``` widget and it does display the ```_result``` value which is the name of the object. Btw this issue has been resolved tho thank you so much for your helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share how I resolved this in case anyone's having the same issue. All I did is just insert a `while (values == null)` inside my `else` statement like this:

```
else {
   values = snapshot.data.value;
   while (values == null){
     return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange),
    );
 }
   lists.clear();
   values.forEach((key, values){
     lists.add(values);
  });
}
```

and then followed by the `ListView.builder()` to display them.

Btw, thank you so much for those who responded!